# Adding records to a dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.4

I want to add records to a dictionary through a for loop. I have seen related questions about this in stack overflow. But I could not figure out the appropriate way.

I am using the following piece of code

```
inpTweets = csv.reader(open('C:/Twitter_crawl/training_sample.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    pair={}
    result={}
for row in inpTweets:
    sentiment = row[0]
    tweet = row[1]
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(tweet)
    pair={'feature':featureVector,'sentiment':sentiment}
    result.update(pair)
```

However when I access the resultant dictionary named result, I can only see the latest record appended.

Comment: Dictionaries can only have **one value** for each key. Perhaps a list of dictionaries would be more appropriate?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to use the `tweet` value (guessing its some sort of id) as a key into a dictionary and then have the `pair` dict as the value?

Answer (score 2):

Your pair dictionary has fixed keys for 'feature' and 'sentiment', so those get overwritten in the update call.

You can solve this with a list of dictionaries:

```
pairs = [ ]
for row in inpTweets:
    sentiment = row[0]
    tweet = row[1]
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(tweet)
    pair={'feature':featureVector,'sentiment':sentiment}
    pairs.append(pair)
```